# Infinite sequences of natural numbers with finite support are equivalent to $\omega^{n_1} c_1 + \omega^{n_2} c_2 + \ldots + \omega^{n_k} c_k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Why exactly do infinite sequences of natural numbers with finite support (having a finite number of non-zero values) correspond to ordinals of the form $\omega^{n_1} c_1 + \omega^{n_2} c_2 + \ldots + \omega^{n_k} c_k$? I found it mentioned on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation) on ordinal exponentiation. Is it possible to explain from the first principles that ordinals of the above form are actually sequences with finite support?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,0,0,\ldots)$ corresponds to the ordinal
$$\omega^n a_n+\omega^{n-1} a_{n-1}+\cdots+\omega a_1+a_0.$$